# How can I add number formats in Qt's model/view framework?

Tags: qt, view, number-formatting

Let's say I have a QTableView with a corresponding model. This view shows numbers only, and I want different number formats for different columns.

Some examples:

- In the price column I want two decimals and a comma as separator.
- In the length column I don't want any decimals but I still want the
  comma separator.
- In the duration column I want the same format as the price column but
  red color if the value is negative.

Now I could do this in the model's data function. `Qt.DisplayRole` handles the number formatting, and `Qt.ForegroundRole` can handle the coloring. While the coloring works as intended, doing the number formatting this way breaks sorting.

Is there a way more straight forward way to achieve this? I tried Googling around to see what I could find, but good examples of what I'm after eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `QStandardItemModel` as your model, you can set the `sortRole` to use, say, `Qt::EditRole` instead of `Qt::DisplayRole`.

If you are using something like `QAbstractItemModel`, you can override the `sort` method and do something similar, i.e. use the `Qt::EditRole` value. You could also wrap a `QSortFilterProxyModel` around your model and override the `lessThan` method.

Comment: Never saw the `sortRole` role before. That's looks like a winner. Thanks.